# phone number validation with space

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I'm very new to jQuery, I just want a regular expression for validating phone numbers in jQuery for one of my text fields.

I want to show phone numbers with a max length of 12 and allow spaces; my pattern is:

`011 233 455 345` or `1111 3333 3333`

I have found validation for this purpose, but did not find exact validation.

Comment: Would 12 digits with no spaces be valid?

Comment: I would STRONGLY recommend using google's libphonenumber library. https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/ This is a recommendation to the entire web... Let's stop being so segmented with our phone number validation

Comment: @ranivder You asked 8 questions but no one is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

1) `/^\d{4} \d{4} \d{4}$/` for `1111 1111 1111`

2) `/^\d{3} \d{3} \d{3} \d{3}$/` for `111 111 111 111`

## Codepad 1

## Codepad 2

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Note there is a space after 0-9 in regular expression.

```
var phone = $('input[name="phone"]').val();(select your field here.)
intRegex = /^[0-9 ]+$/;
if((phone.length > 12) || (!intRegex.test(phone)))
{
  alert('Please enter a valid phone number.');
  return false;
}
```